# How convert audio raw to flac in Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, flac

I recording audio with class audoiRecord. Now I want convert audio raw file to *flac format. I convert *raw file to wav next way:

```
private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = sampleRate;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * sampleRate * channels/8;
    byte[] data_pcm = new byte[mAudioBufferSize];
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        Log.i(TAG,"File size: " + totalDataLen);
        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
        longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);
        while(in.read(data_pcm) != -1){
            out.write(data_pcm);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This piece of code is responsible for the file header

```
private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                 FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                 long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                 long byteRate) throws IOException {

     byte[] header = new byte[44];

     header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
     header[1] = 'I';
     header[2] = 'F';
     header[3] = 'F';
     header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
     header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[8] = 'W';
     header[9] = 'A';
     header[10] = 'V';
     header[11] = 'E';
     header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
     header[13] = 'm';
     header[14] = 't';
     header[15] = ' ';
     header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
     header[17] = 0;
     header[18] = 0;
     header[19] = 0;
     header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
     header[21] = 0;
     header[22] = (byte) channels;
     header[23] = 0;
     header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
     header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
     header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
     header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
     header[33] = 0;
     header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
     header[35] = 0;
     header[36] = 'd';
     header[37] = 'a';
     header[38] = 't';
     header[39] = 'a';
     header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
     header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
     header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
     header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

     out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

I do not understand what should be the parameters of the *flac file

Comment: hello user, if you are able to convert raw file to flac then please share your way so that i could help myself. I am stuck in this problem from 1 week. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an encoder to convert pcm data to flac format. You cannot just change the header and expect the content to work as flac.

Android (at least till 4.1) does not include a FLAC encoder, although there is a decoder supported from 3.1 onwards (Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

<s>I do not have direct experience, but have seen people use ffmpeg as a flac encoder. This project [audioboo-android](https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android), which contains the native libFLAC/libFLAC++ encoder, looks interesting.</s>

Comment: Hi, can you please update the link for `audioboo-android` because it is dead.

Answer (score 1):

So, from Android 4.1 you can do so:

Initializing:

```java
MediaCodecList mcl = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.REGULAR_CODECS);

MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/flac");
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64000);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, SAMPLE_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, NUM_CHANNELS);

String codecname = mcl.findEncoderForFormat(format);
Log.w(TAG, "Codec: "+codecname);

MediaCodec codec = null;
try
{
    codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecname);
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

codec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
MediaFormat outputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(); // option B

long usec = 1000000000L * FRAME_SIZE/SAMPLE_RATE;
MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufinfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
bufinfo.set(0, FRAME_SIZE * NUM_CHANNELS * 2, usec, 0);

codec.start();

byte[] inBuf = new byte[FRAME_SIZE * NUM_CHANNELS * 2];
byte[] encBuf = new byte[10240];
```

In the recorder loop:

```java
int encoded = 0;
int inputBufferId = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
if (inputBufferId >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
    // fill inputBuffer with valid data
    inputBuffer.put(inBuf, 0, inBuf.length);
    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, inBuf.length, usec, 0);
}

int outputBufferId = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufinfo, 1000);
if (outputBufferId >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);
    MediaFormat bufferFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(outputBufferId); // option A
    // bufferFormat is identical to outputFormat
    // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.

    outputBuffer.rewind();
    encoded = outputBuffer.remaining();
    outputBuffer.get(encBuf, 0, encoded);

    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false);
} else if (outputBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
    // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
    // Can ignore if using getOutputFormat(outputBufferId)
    outputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(); // option B
}

if (encoded > 0)
{
    // Process data in encBuf
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the result of AudioRecord.read()? Also, where/how do you save the result to a file? Does it hook up to MediaMuxer somehow?

Comment: Also, what is FRAME_SIZE and how do we determine that?

Comment: Also, in encBuf how was the number 10240 calculated and what should we change it to if we're trying to encode other formats/sample rates?

Comment: @ryan-tremblay so many good questions :-) AudioRecord.read is inBuf in the example. I hadn't goal to write it to file, I just sent the result to server, so I can't clarify this question.

Comment: @RyanTremblay About FRAME_SIZE. It is very important question for decoding - by which chunks to put data to decoder. But for encoding it almost irrelevant. I used value 240.

Comment: @RyanTremblay About encBuf. It must be just something enough big to fit the output the encoder. So feel your free to increase it if it doesn't work, but don't forget about limit of memory.

Comment: @RyanTremblay I remembered about question #1. On the server I wrote the output of encoder to a file without any preprocessing (it is D code, so it is not relevant for topic). These files can be read with `flac` utility with -F flag with ignoring warnings. But if you want to avoid warnings you need to learn flac format and add some headers.

Comment: Thanks! @future travelers: Here's another wonderful implementation: https://github.com/nieldeokar/WhatsappAudioRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nieldeokar/whatsappaudiorecorder/recorder/AudioRecordThread.java

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure java FLAC encoder: http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net

Some of the classes use the javax apis, but they can be safely deleted without affecting the main encoder classes.

Here's some sample code. The `record` object is of type `AudioRecord`

```
try {
                    // Path to write files to
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/test").getAbsolutePath();

                    String fileName = name+".flac";
                    String externalStorage = path;
                    File file = new File(externalStorage + File.separator + fileName);

                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    short sData[] = new short[BufferElements2Rec];

                    FileOutputStream os = null;
                    try {
                        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    FLACEncoder flacEncoder = new FLACEncoder();
                    StreamConfiguration streamConfiguration = new StreamConfiguration(1,StreamConfiguration.MIN_BLOCK_SIZE,StreamConfiguration.MAX_BLOCK_SIZE,44100,16);

                    FLACFileOutputStream flacOut = new FLACFileOutputStream(os);
                    flacEncoder.setStreamConfiguration(streamConfiguration);
                    flacEncoder.setOutputStream(flacOut);
                    flacEncoder.openFLACStream();


                    record.startRecording();

                    int totalSamples = 0;

                    while (isRecording) {
                        record.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
                        totalSamples+=BufferElements2Rec;

                        flacEncoder.addSamples(short2int(sData),BufferElements2Rec);

                        flacEncoder.encodeSamples(BufferElements2Rec, false);
                    }

                    int available = flacEncoder.samplesAvailableToEncode();
                    while(flacEncoder.encodeSamples(available,true) < available) {
                        available = flacEncoder.samplesAvailableToEncode();
                    }
                    try {
                        flacOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    record.stop();
                } catch(IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

                record.release();
                record = null;
}
```

For converting the short data into int data:

```
private int[] short2int(short[] sData) {
    int length = sData.length;
    int[] iData = new int[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        iData[i] = sData[i];
    }
    return iData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/nieldeokar/WhatsappAudioRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nieldeokar/whatsappaudiorecorder/recorder/AudioRecordThread.java

My solution for save recording in .m4a file while working speech recognition :

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import timber.log.Timber;

public class SpeechRecognizer {

private static final int CHANNELS = 1;
private static final int BIT_RATE = 32000;
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private static final int SAMPLE_RATE_INDEX = 4;

protected static final String TAG = SpeechRecognizer.class.getSimpleName();

public int bufferSize;

public final Collection<RecognitionListener> listeners = new HashSet();

public final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public final Recognizer recognizer;
private Thread recognizerThread;

public final AudioRecord recorder;

private SoundAmplitudeCallback soundAmplitudeCallback;

private File recordFile = null;

private boolean isRecordingToFileEnabled = false;
private boolean isRecordingToFilePrepared = false;
private boolean isContinueRecordingToFile = false;

public interface SoundAmplitudeCallback {
    void onAmplitude(int amplitude);
}

public void setSoundAmplitudeCallback(SoundAmplitudeCallback callback) {
    soundAmplitudeCallback = callback;
}

public SpeechRecognizer(Mabcd model) throws IOException {
    this.recognizer = new Recognizer(model, SAMPLE_RATE);
    this.bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    this.recorder = createAudioRecorder(this.bufferSize);

    if (this.recorder.getState() == 0) {
        this.recorder.release();
        throw new IOException("Failed to initialize recorder. Microphone might  be already in use.");
    }
}

public void addListener(RecognitionListener listener) {
    synchronized (this.listeners) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeListener(RecognitionListener listener) {
    synchronized (this.listeners) {
        this.listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

public boolean startListening() {
    if (this.recognizerThread != null) {
        return false;
    }
    this.recognizerThread = new RecognizerThread(this);
    this.recognizerThread.start();

    return true;
}

public boolean startListening(int timeout) {
    if (this.recognizerThread != null) {
        return false;
    }
    this.recognizerThread = new RecognizerThread(timeout);
    this.recognizerThread.start();
    return true;
}

private boolean stopRecognizerThread() {
    if (this.recognizerThread == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        this.recognizerThread.interrupt();
        this.recognizerThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    this.recognizerThread = null;
    return true;
}

public void startRecordToFile(File fileRecord) {
    this.recordFile = fileRecord;
    isRecordingToFileEnabled = true;
}

public void resumeRecordToFile(File fileRecord) {
    this.recordFile = fileRecord;
    isContinueRecordingToFile = true;
    isRecordingToFileEnabled = true;
    isRecordingToFilePrepared = false;
}

public void stopRecordToFile() {
    isRecordingToFileEnabled = false;
    isRecordingToFilePrepared = false;
    isContinueRecordingToFile = false;
}

public boolean stop() {
    boolean result = stopRecognizerThread();
    if (result) {
        this.mainHandler.post(new ResultEvent(this.recognizer.Rabcd(), true));
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean cancel() {
    boolean result = stopRecognizerThread();
    this.recognizer.Rabcd();
    return result;
}

public void shutdown() {
    this.recorder.release();
}

private final class RecognizerThread extends Thread {
    private static final int NO_TIMEOUT = -1;
    private int remainingSamples;
    private int timeoutSamples;
    VoiceRecorder voiceRecorder = null;

    public RecognizerThread(int timeout) {
        if (timeout != NO_TIMEOUT) {
            this.timeoutSamples = (SpeechRecognizer.SAMPLE_RATE * timeout) / 1000;
        } else {
            this.timeoutSamples = NO_TIMEOUT;
        }
        this.remainingSamples = this.timeoutSamples;
    }

    public RecognizerThread(SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer) {
        this(NO_TIMEOUT);
    }

    public void run() {
        voiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder();

        SpeechRecognizer.this.recorder.startRecording();
        if (SpeechRecognizer.this.recorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {
            SpeechRecognizer.this.recorder.stop();
            SpeechRecognizer.this.mainHandler.post(new OnErrorEvent(new IOException("Failed to start recording. Microphone might be already in use.")));

            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[SpeechRecognizer.this.bufferSize];

        while (!interrupted() && (this.timeoutSamples == NO_TIMEOUT || this.remainingSamples > 0)) {
            int nread = SpeechRecognizer.this.recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            if (soundAmplitudeCallback != null) {
                int max = 0;
                for (short s : buffer) {
                    if (Math.abs(s) > max) {
                        max = Math.abs(s);
                    }
                }
                soundAmplitudeCallback.onAmplitude(max);
            }

            if (nread < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error reading audio buffer");
            }

            voiceRecorder.recording(nread, buffer);

            if (SpeechRecognizer.this.recognizer.Aabcd(buffer, nread)) {
                SpeechRecognizer.this.mainHandler.post(new ResultEvent(SpeechRecognizer.this.recognizer.Rabcd(), true));
            } else {
                SpeechRecognizer.this.mainHandler.post(new ResultEvent(SpeechRecognizer.this.recognizer.Pabcd(), false));
            }

            if (this.timeoutSamples != NO_TIMEOUT) {
                this.remainingSamples -= nread;
            }
        }

        voiceRecorder.shutdown();
        SpeechRecognizer.this.recorder.stop();

        SpeechRecognizer.this.mainHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages((Object) null);
        if (this.timeoutSamples != NO_TIMEOUT && this.remainingSamples <= 0) {
            SpeechRecognizer.this.mainHandler.post(new TimeoutEvent());
        }
    }
}

/*
* Voice Recorder to file
* */
private class VoiceRecorder{
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    MediaCodec mediaCodec = null;

    void recording(int nread, byte[] buffer){
        /*step 1 prepare file*/
        if (isRecordingToFileEnabled && !isRecordingToFilePrepared) {
            //if we continue recording not create new file
            if (recordFile == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Record file is null");
            }

            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(recordFile, isContinueRecordingToFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            if (mediaCodec == null){
                try {
                    mediaCodec = createMediaCodec(bufferSize);
                    mediaCodec.start();
                    Timber.d("mediaCodec.start()");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            isRecordingToFilePrepared = true;
        }
        /*prepare file*/

        /*step 2 recording*/
        if (isRecordingToFileEnabled && isRecordingToFilePrepared) {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null){
                    boolean success = handleCodecInput(nread, buffer, mediaCodec, Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
                    if (success)
                        handleCodecOutput(mediaCodec, bufferInfo, fileOutputStream);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        /*recording*/

        /*step 3 finish recording and save to file*/
        if (!isRecordingToFileEnabled && fileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                VoiceRecorder.this.shutdown();

                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream = null;

                Timber.d("Finishing file");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        /*finish recording and save to file*/
    }

    void shutdown(){
        if (mediaCodec != null){
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
        }
    }
}

private abstract class RecognitionEvent implements Runnable {

    public abstract void execute(RecognitionListener recognitionListener);

    private RecognitionEvent() {
    }

    public void run() {
        for (RecognitionListener listener : (RecognitionListener[]) SpeechRecognizer.this.listeners.toArray(new RecognitionListener[0])) {
            execute(listener);
        }
    }
}

private class ResultEvent extends RecognitionEvent {
    private final boolean finalResult;
    protected final String hypothesis;

    ResultEvent(String hypothesis2, boolean finalResult2) {
        super();
        this.hypothesis = hypothesis2;
        this.finalResult = finalResult2;
    }


    public void execute(RecognitionListener listener) {
        if (this.finalResult) {
            listener.onResult(this.hypothesis);
        } else {
            listener.onPartialResult(this.hypothesis);
        }
    }
}

private class OnErrorEvent extends RecognitionEvent {
    private final Exception exception;

    OnErrorEvent(Exception exception2) {
        super();
        this.exception = exception2;
    }


    public void execute(RecognitionListener listener) {
        listener.onError(this.exception);
    }
}

private class TimeoutEvent extends RecognitionEvent {
    private TimeoutEvent() {
        super();
    }


    public void execute(RecognitionListener listener) {
        listener.onTimeout();
    }
}

private AudioRecord createAudioRecorder(int bufferSize) {
    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize * 10);

    if (android.media.audiofx.NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable()) {
        android.media.audiofx.NoiseSuppressor noiseSuppressor = android.media.audiofx.NoiseSuppressor
                .create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
        if (noiseSuppressor != null) {
            noiseSuppressor.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    if (android.media.audiofx.AutomaticGainControl.isAvailable()) {
        android.media.audiofx.AutomaticGainControl automaticGainControl = android.media.audiofx.AutomaticGainControl
                .create(recorder.getAudioSessionId());
        if (automaticGainControl != null) {
            automaticGainControl.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    return recorder;
}

private MediaCodec createMediaCodec(int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = new MediaFormat();

    mediaFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, SAMPLE_RATE);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, CHANNELS);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, bufferSize);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);

    try {
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).w(e);
        mediaCodec.release();
        throw new IOException(e);
    }

    return mediaCodec;
}

private boolean handleCodecInput(int length,
                                 byte[] buffer,
                                 MediaCodec mediaCodec,
                                 boolean running) {

    if (length == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE ||
            length == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION ||
            length != bufferSize) {

        if (length != bufferSize) {
            Timber.tag(TAG).d( "length != BufferSize calling onRecordFailed");
//                if (onRecorderFailedListener != null) {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "length != BufferSize calling onRecordFailed");
//                    onRecorderFailedListener.onRecorderFailed();
//                }
            return false;
        }
    }

    int codecInputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(10 * 1000);

    if (codecInputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer codecBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(codecInputBufferIndex);
        codecBuffer.clear();
        codecBuffer.put(buffer);
        mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(codecInputBufferIndex, 0, length, 0, running ? 0 : MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
    }

    return true;
}

private void handleCodecOutput(MediaCodec mediaCodec,
                               MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo,
                               OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    int codecOutputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);

    while (codecOutputBufferIndex != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
        if (codecOutputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer encoderOutputBuffer = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(codecOutputBufferIndex);

            encoderOutputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
            encoderOutputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);

            if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) {
                byte[] header = createAdtsHeader(bufferInfo.size - bufferInfo.offset);


                outputStream.write(header);

                byte[] data = new byte[encoderOutputBuffer.remaining()];
                encoderOutputBuffer.get(data);
                outputStream.write(data);
            }

            encoderOutputBuffer.clear();

            mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(codecOutputBufferIndex, false);
        }

        codecOutputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    }
}

private byte[] createAdtsHeader(int length) {
    int frameLength = length + 7;
    byte[] adtsHeader = new byte[7];

    adtsHeader[0] = (byte) 0xFF; // Sync Word
    adtsHeader[1] = (byte) 0xF1; // MPEG-4, Layer (0), No CRC
    adtsHeader[2] = (byte) ((MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC - 1) << 6);
    adtsHeader[2] |= (((byte) SAMPLE_RATE_INDEX) << 2);
    adtsHeader[2] |= (((byte) CHANNELS) >> 2);
    adtsHeader[3] = (byte) (((CHANNELS & 3) << 6) | ((frameLength >> 11) & 0x03));
    adtsHeader[4] = (byte) ((frameLength >> 3) & 0xFF);
    adtsHeader[5] = (byte) (((frameLength & 0x07) << 5) | 0x1f);
    adtsHeader[6] = (byte) 0xFC;

    return adtsHeader;
}
}
```

[java](/questions/tagged/java) [android](/questions/tagged/android) [speech](/questions/tagged/speech) [recognition](/questions/tagged/recognition) [recording](/questions/tagged/recording) [file](/questions/tagged/file) [pcm](/questions/tagged/pcm) [m4a](/questions/tagged/m4a)