# How can I convert Android recorded audio input to flac in Xamarin

Tags: google-api, xamarin, speech-recognition, android-mediarecorder, flac

We are creating an andoid app with Xamarin that needs to work under lock screen. In particular, to be able to recognize voice that comes in via mic.Under lock screen we are unable to use an "on-board" Google Voice recognition APIs. Google provides an online voice recognition service, but it requires an application to provide a flac-formated input for recognition.

Is there a way that we can generate flac encoded voice data to send to google speech api that is avaiable here:
https://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/demos/speech.html

In our application we were recording audio as shown here:
http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/record_audio/
(using `MediaRecorder` class)

Comment: There are quite some questions like your one with solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060221/how-convert-audio-raw-to-flac-in-android?rq=1. For continuous offline recognition of keywords you might want to consider [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it will be way more efficient and will not depend on network.